# Why is PhpStorm saving the file onKeyup instead of on Tab exit

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am working on a JavaScript file and PhpStorm seems to save the file on keyup. The problem with this is that it is breaking up my minification as the file its being saved before I am done writing the correct syntax.

I have gone to `File > Settings > Appearance and Behavior` but seem not to find the option for this.

Comment: Please show your File Watcher settings (if you use it .. which you may since you do "minification" task somehow).